# How to run rails db:seed once for all Elastic Beanstalk instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying an RoR app to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (EB). To prepare the container by pre-loading the data, I am running a rake task using a pre-deploy script:

```
container_commands:
  01seed:
    command: rails db:seed:dataset size=$SIZE --trace
```

The problem is, if I spin up four instances using `eb create --scale 4`, the task runs four times which causes my deployment to fail due to violation of unique key constraint. How can I run the task for one instance per deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this the wrong way. Even if you managed to find a way to run `rails db:seed` once per deployment, you'd still have a problem if your auto-scaling rules added an instance.

Instead, you could modify your seeds file to allow it to be run multiple times. I've done this using [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) and [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) to only create the seed data if it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
container_commands:
  01seed:
    command: rails db:seed:dataset size=$SIZE --trace
    leader_only: true
```

pretty sure this still works for anyone who lands here